# Почему не срабатывает subscribe() после combineLatest()?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Я начал писать простенький скрипт игры, но столкнулся с проблемой.

В коде создаётся 2 потока - `player`, `walls`:

```js
const Helper = function() {
  this.randomIntFromZero = function(maxExclusive) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxExclusive));
  };
};
helper = new Helper();


const move = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keydown');


const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;


const WALLLS_CNT = 10;
const wallWidth = 16;
const wallHeight = 16;
const wallColor = '#ccc';

const walls = Rx.Observable
 .range(1, 10)
 .map(() => {
  return {
   x: helper.randomIntFromZero(canvas.width - wallWidth),
   y: helper.randomIntFromZero(canvas.height - wallHeight)
  };
 })
  
const deltaCoord = 5;
const canvasColor = '#fff';

const player = move.map(
 e => {
   const coords = { x: 0, y: 0 }

  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
   coords.x -= (player.x <= 0) ? 0 : deltaCoord;
  }

  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
   coords.y -= (player.y <= 0) ? 0 : deltaCoord;
  }

  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
   coords.x += (player.x + player.width >= canvas.width) ? 0 : deltaCoord;
  }

  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
   coords.y += (player.y + player.width >= canvas.height) ? 0 : deltaCoord;
  }

  return coords;
 }
)  
.startWith({ x: 0, y: 0 })  

Rx.Observable.combineLatest((player, walls) => {
 console.log(player, walls);
})
.subscribe((player, walls) => {
 console.log('player', player);
 console.log('walls', walls);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.5.2/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

[JSFidddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zlodiak/raeh0w9g/3/)

Проблема в том, что `console.logs` из последнего куска кода не выводятся в консоль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте последние две строчки на

```
const example = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(player, walls);

example.subscribe(
   ([player, walls]) => {
    console.log('player', player);
    console.log('walls', walls);      
  });
```